# In Rails 3.x, how to design a view for a nested resource that refers to the parent resource?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, nested, url-routing

Let's say I have a nested resource like in the Rails guide example:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end
```

This routes a call to /magazines/newsweek/ads to the AdsController#index. It requires a magazine_id in the URL...how should I go about creating a view that is based off of a template used for Ads#index yet also includes the context of the parent resource?

For example, all parent resources that have Ads will have a table list of those ads. But I'd like the top of the view to include boilerplate information for each Magazine. If /magazines/newsweek/ads goes directly to the generic AdsController#index, how do I make that #index view aware of the need to include boilerplate generated from the Magazine model?

And if other models have relationships to ads (TelevisionShow has_many :ads), I'd like AdsController#index to react differently to those as well.

EDIT:

This is how I've done such things in the past, going through MagazinesController. Let's say I *want* a separate Magazine#show action...the routes would be:

```
resources :magazines 
resources :ads
get "magazines/:id/ads", :controller=>"companies", :action=>"ads"
```

And the controller would be:

```
class MagazinesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    ...
  end

  def ads
    ...
  end

end
```

And then Magazine#ads would have a partial for ads listings that would be shared across all other types of resources.

Makes sense to me, but that route seems like it could somehow be DRYer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you should be working in the magazine controller.

```
#Magazine_controller
def show
  @magazine = Magazine.find(params[:id])
  @ads = @magazine.ads
end
```

Then in your view just render a partial for your collection of ads. Your ads partial will be saved in the ads area.  So in your veiw:

```
<%= render :partial => "ads/ad", :collection => @ads %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: Thanks...that is how I've done this before and I'm glad I wasn't just doing it as a shortcut that went against convention. I had wondered if built in nested resources routing was the "Rails way" to do it.