# For arbitrary routes in Rails 3.x, how can I use UrlHelper to access them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

So I have a route in routes.rb like this:

```
get "customers/:id/payments", :controller=>"customers", :action=>"payments"
```

What would be the UrlHelper that would generate this, if any, when doing this in a view:

```
link_to customer.name, customers_payments_path(customer)
```

(customers_payments_path is not valid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
get "customers/:id/payments", :controller=>"customers", :action=>"payments", :as => 'customer_payments'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

From the above link:

> You can specify a name for any route using the :as option.

Answer (score 2):

I like Gazler's answer if it's only a one-off route, but if you've already got resource routes for customers then I would define this route like this:

```
resources :customers do
  member do
    get :payments
  end
end
```

This way, you would still have the standard `customers_path` and `customer_path` helpers you'd normally get from a resource route, but it would also generate `customer_payments_path` in a shorter syntax.

Comment: Nice addition, I hadn't considered utilizing the existing resource.

Comment: Thank you, thank you. You were probably unaware of this, but this particular question spawned from a prior question I asked about nested resources, and your routing answer solves *that* one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109201/in-rails-3-x-how-to-design-a-view-for-a-nested-resource-that-refers-to-the-paren

Comment: But I have to give Gazier the accepted solution as he gave the most appropriate answer given the particular description of the problem. I'd give you credit if I could for being psychic

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the :as parameter to add a name to the route, so you can access it from a url_helper:

```
get "confirmations/:code" => "confirmations#show", :as => "show_confirmation"
```

Then in your views/controllers/tests:

```
link_to "Confirm", show_confirmation_url(confirmation)
```